# Java HashSet duplicates comparison

Tags: java, list, duplicates, hashset

I have a class `Person` which contains `String firstName, lastName`. I want to insert instances of this class into a `List`, but I don't want to insert duplicates.

How do I use a `HashSet` such that it uses something like `firstName+lastName` to figure out duplicates?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need an `equals()` and a `hashCode()` method in your `Person` class.

`equals()` is straightforward, and for `hashCode()` the easiest solution is:

```
public int hashCode() {
  return Arrays.hashCode( new Object[] { firstName, lastName } );
}
```

Although if your `Person` object is immutable (as it should be, if you're putting it in a HashSet), you should cache this value.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make your `.equals()` method return `true` for two `Person`s with the same first and last name.  You need to also implement the `.hashcode()` method to ensure that two equal object have the same hashcode.

Your question refers to using a List, and then mentions HashSet.  If preserving insertion order is important then a `HashSet` is not what you want, you should use [`LinkedHashSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html).

Answer (score 1):

You should just use a `Set` instead of a `List`. If you care about insertion order, use a [`LinkedHashSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html).

Answer (score 1):

Important -> You need to implement equals AND hashcode

Always implement both. And they must be consistent-> if 2 object are equals they must have the same hashcode.

THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT.
READ AGAIN. :)

HashSets and HashMaps use hashcode and equals to compare elements. Diferent elements may have the same hashcode, but they are not equals